# currentsubsection not showing before subsection slide begins

Tags: beamer

I would like to use AtBeginSection[] to display the currentsubsection before entering that subsection's slide. This works fine with \section (I get a slide that displays the currentsection before we begin that section), but not with \subsection. I've gone in circles with this a bit, and now I need some help. Here's the code

```
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{NYU}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title[ShortTitle]{LongTitle}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{\today}
\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{nyu_shanghai}}

 \AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{Agenda}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Agenda}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Section1}
hello
\begin{frame}{frame1}
    hi frame
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection1}
i'm in the first subsection now but Subsection1 is not displayed before i enter the slide
\begin{frame}{Frame2}
    asfdsaf
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated. My first time posting here, so I apologize if the format needs work. I appreciate all feedback. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would also need a `\AtBeginSubsection` for the agenda slide to be shown before `\subsection`; it's the same code as `\AtBeginSection`.

Comment: Thanks @LianTzeLim ! This worked like a charm..